# If $f_n \to f$ and for every $n > 0$ $f_n$ is uniformly continuous then f is uniformly continuous. Where did my proof fail?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, fake-proofs, pointwise-convergence

> Let $[a,b] \subseteq \Bbb R$, let $f_n:[a,b] \to \Bbb R \space\space$ such that $\forall n>0 \space\space f_n$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Let $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$, Suppose that $f_n \to f \space$ then $f\space$ is also uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$

This is a question that came to my mind when I was looking at a proof of this where $f_n \rightrightarrows f$.

It was raised to my awareness that the statement is not true in this case because its p.w convergence but Im not sure where the proof I state beneath fails, and why it doesnt fail for uniform convergence?
any explanation would be  really helpful.

**Incorrect proof:**
let $\epsilon > 0\space$, $f_n$ is uniformly continuous so there exists $\delta_0 > 0$ such that for every $x,y \in [a,b]$ if $|x-y| < \delta_0$ then $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

define $\delta = \delta_0$ let $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$. since $f_n \to f$ then there exists $N_{0} \in \Bbb N \space\space , N_{0}>0$ such that for every $n \geq N_{0}$. $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

And there exists $N_{1} \in \Bbb N \space\space , N_{1}>0$ such that for every $n \geq N_{1}$. $|f_n(y) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

let $n = \max\{N_{0}, N_{1} \} + 1$, So: $$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f(x) - f_n(x) + f_n(x) - f_n(y) + f_n(y) - f(y)| \\\ \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)| < 3\frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon$$

Comment: The proof is faulty because of sloppy handling of universal dequantifications: you start out with an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ and use the uniform continuity hypothesis for a certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in order to derive the existence of a corresponding $\delta>0$ for **that specific term** $f_n$ in your sequence of functions. Then, after fixing two arbitrary arguments $x$ and $y$ at less than $\delta$ distance apart in the domain of definition (common to all the functions in your sequence) you proceed to exploit *(to be cont.)*

Comment: *(cont.)* to exploit the convergence of sequences $\left(f_n(x)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ respectively $\left(f_n(y)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in order to obtain the two threshold indices $N_0$ and $N_1$ such that the respective $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$-bounding inequalities are valid. Finally, you consider the number $\max \{N_0, N_1\}+1$ and make a syntactical error: you denote it with the same designator $n$ that you have already introduced previously in a different context, thus totally tripping yourself up!

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Interesting. Thanks for putting emphasis on “**that specific term $f_n$**” really made me realize how sneaky this mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main flaw is that the value of $n=\max(N_1,N_2) + 1$ is based on the quantities $x,y,\epsilon$. Therefore, as $x,y$ vary, so will this $n$. So, you cannot pick any "universal" $n$ at the start to use in your final triangle inequality, as varying $x,y$ will change the $n$, which will change the $\delta_0(n)$ you discuss at the beginning of your proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, So if i understood correctly, when we pick another value of x and y the value of n changes and so $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)|$ is now relevant to a different $\delta$ say $\delta_1 \neq \delta_0 \space$. so we could be picking x and y that satisfy $|x-y| < \delta_0 \space$ but $|x-y| > \delta_1$ and therefore we cant say anything about $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)|$ being less than $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.